# Any one know any replacement library for pxssh which also cross platform for ssh operation.?

Tags: python, paramiko, pexcept

I need to login the linux setup with non-root user. Then switch to root user
to execute interactive command .

I have used pxssh module in pexpect but not work properly. It get failed some time while synchronous the command prompt. It also not work with windows machine.
I need some module which also work like pxssh and execute on windows machine.
and also have all feature which is similar to pxssh.

Comment: library recommendations are strictly off-topic on SO

Answer (score 0):

got the library which execute like pxssh .

https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
 [plink.exe](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)

Use the timeout flag with PopenSpawn to wait for the connection to establish.

```
p = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('plink.exe -telnet 192.168.0.1 -P 23', timeout=1)
#p = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('cmd', timeout=1) try this too
child.send('ipconfig')
child.expect('Wireless', timeout=None)
```